# Import python script in Flask to make it shareabale

Tags: python, flask

I have a python script `Flow.py` that has a function `choked()` which takes user input and performs a set of algebraic calculations and prints the results (see sample code below). I want to make this file shareable with my colleagues.

I tried it two ways:
1 - Making it a .exe file
2 - Using Flask

**Problems faced**:
1 - For .exe file, I tried `cx_Freeze` and `pyinstaller`, but both gives error. The executable file closes immediately upon clicking it.
2 - In Flask, upon running in shell, it doesn't give any error, however on running on localhost, nothing happens

```
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def choked():     #this is my Flow.py
    
    e1 = input('Enter value 1: ')  # var type = str
    e2 = input('Enter value 2: ')  # var type = str
    e3 = input('Enter value 3: ')  # var type = str
        
    G = e1*e2*e3

    print ()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with that is Flask is used for routing and `input` expects to read from `stdin`, you need to define it as a POST request, where e1, e2, e3 are specified as URI parameters then do the computation on them and return the response.

```py
@app.route('/<string:e1>/<string:e2>/<string:e3>'):
def choked(e1, e2, e3):
    G = e1 * e2* e3
    return G
```

And when flask is running--

```
$ curl localhost:8000/<e1>/<e2>/<e3>
```